# Where do assembly attributes go?

Tags: c#, attributes

This seems like a silly question, but are there rules for where you can put Assembly specific attributes (which would be terrible if true)? For example if I try to put:

```
[assembly: RadAttribute]
```

in a class, it just laughs at me and pretends like it doesn't know what `RadAttribute` is. I do notice that `AssemblyInfo.cs` seems to contain some assembly specific attributes, so why is it that they can go in there, but nowhere else?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Assembly attributes like that must be before any `namespace` or `class` (or other type) declarations in the code file in question.

Answer (score 2):

I'd usually put it outside of any class declarations, and indeed namespace declarations.

It could go anywhere (except within a class), and AssemblyInfo.cs has no special properties - but is simply a place used by convention to store assembly attributes.

Comment: No, you can't put it _after_ a class or namespace, for example. And not inside any set of `{ }`, like inside a `namespace` declaration.

Comment: @JeppeStigNielsen - you seem to be correct on testing. Oddly, the C# Language Specification seems to indicate that assembly and module attributes can occur at global scope, but in practise the compiler chokes.

Of course, you'd hope no one would bury such a declaration anyway.

Comment: We _could_ create a new question here on SO asking where in the C# Language Specification does it say that a global attribute cannot come after a `namespace` declaration or type declaration? It's a very little issue, but still on-topic, I guess. Will you or shall I?

Comment: When you read the section on _Compilation units_ in the spec, paragraph 9.1 in the version 5 of the document _C# Language Specification_ you do get the impression that global attributes must come before any "namespace-member-declaration", within the compilation unit.